# Update entity with one to many list Entityframwork 5

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I use with entity framework 5 code first.
I create an entity that contain one collection.
I tried all and I didn't found how to update this entity.

```
public class TaskExtention
{
        public TaskExtention()
        {
            RequiredFeatures = new HashSet<FeatureTaskRequirment>();
        }

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] 
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int ExternalSystemId { get; set; }

        public ICollection<FeatureTaskRequirment> RequiredFeatures { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var other = obj as TaskExtention;
            if (other == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return Id == other.Id;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Id.GetHashCode();
        }
}
```

My Last try:

```
using (var db = GetContext())
{
     TaskExtention currTask = GetByExternalID(ExternalID);
     if (currTask != null)
     {
        currTask.RequiredFeatures = FeatuersToUpdate;
        db.TaskExtentions.Attach(currTask);
        db.Entry(currTask).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
     }
}
```

Please help me to know how to update the entity.

Comment: Are you getting an exception or anything? Does it seem to work but entity just isn't updated in db? Are you sure GetByExternalID() isn't returning null?

Comment: Yes, Isn't updated. It look like it's dont do nothing.

Comment: Are you sure GetByExternalId is returning an entity? What happens if you set RequiredFeatures after you attach it?

Answer (score 0):

if the entity doesn't already exist in the database then you should use Add method instead of Attach. Attach is used with entities  that are in the database but not part of the context. 
Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj592676) for detail.